# Maximum value of $l+m$

Tags: calculus

If $l^{2} + m^{2} = 1$ then the maximum value of $ l+m $ is?

We can consider it to be a circle of radius one around $l=0$ and $m=0$ but how do I differentiate this equation to find the stationary points? Intuitively I feel that this will achieve its maxima when $l=m$ but how do I prove it mathematically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $\bf{Cauchy\; Schwartx\;Inequality}$

$$(l^2+m^2)(1^2+1^2)\geq (l+m)^2$$ and equality hold when $\displaystyle l=m$

So $$l+m\leq \sqrt{2}\;,$$ When $\displaystyle l=m=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Beat me by 43 seconds. Fortunately, our answers agree.

Comment: Don't worry. I have just started with Mathematics  and have a lots of doubts to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$2=2l^2+2m^2=(l+m)^2+(l-m)^2.$$
Since the sum $(l+m)^2+(l-m)^2$ is a constant, to maximize $(l+m)^2$ we minimize $(l-m)^2$, so we set $l=m$.

It follows that the maximum value of $(l+m)^2$ is $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, $l^2+m^2=1 \implies (l, m) = (\sin \theta, \cos \theta)$ for some $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$. So we need max of:
$$\sin \theta + \cos \theta = \sqrt2 \sin(\theta + \tfrac{\pi}4) \le \sqrt2$$

Answer (score 0):

Use LaGrange Multipliers.  The maximum occurs when $\frac{d}{dl}(l^2+m^2-1) = \frac{d}{dm}(l^2+m^2-1)$, i.e. $2l = 2m$, so $l=m$.

Answer (score 0):

$s
=l+m
=l+\sqrt{1-l^2}
$
so
$s'
=1+\frac12(-2l)/\sqrt{1-l^2}
=1-l/\sqrt{1-l^2}
$.

Therefore,
if $s' = 0$
then
$l = \sqrt{1-l^2}$
or
$l^2 = 1-l^2
$
or
$l^2 = \frac12$
or
$l = \sqrt{2}/2$.
so that
$m^2 = \frac12$
and
$l+m = \sqrt{2}$.